# Deep indexing of collection with hierarchical dozer

Tags: java, dozer

How to map data from the collection in dozer. Sharing the following sample. Kindly help me with same.

```
<field>
<a>person.addresses[0].address</a>
<b>employee.address</b>
</field>
```

How to iterate pojo class and map data from source to destination ?

I am getting the following exception

```
Getting Mapping Exceptions org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field.
```

Comment: I am able to map pojoA to pojoB and collectionA to collectionB. But in this case i am trying to map a single class from the List. I have person class  which contain list of address and i want to map the first address of person class with the employee address class.

Answer (score 0):

Try deep index mapping hint

```
<field>
    <a>person.addresses[0].address</a>
    <b>employee.address</b>
    <a-deep-index-hint>org.yourpackage.person.entity.Address</a-deep-index-hint>      
</field>
```

or

Check your setter methods, If you have Unusual setter/getter methods you can specify the custom setter/getter methods.

```
<field>
    <a get-method="getAddress" >person.addresses[0].address</a>
    <b set-method="setAddress" >employee.address</b>
</field>
```